# siunitx and vertical line

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I used `siunitx` so numbers in a table can be aligned. However, a vertical line is lost between two columns. Also, numbers in the last column are not vertically aligned. How can this fixed? Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\begin{tabular}{| L{4.2cm} | C{2.6cm} | S[table-format=9.6] |  C{2.6cm} | C{2.6cm} | C{2.6cm} |} 
\hline 
& \bfseries 1988& {\centering} {\bfseries 1989} & \bfseries 1990 & \bfseries Change \\ [2ex]
\hline
Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\ [1.8ex]
\hline
Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\ [1.8ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing a `|` character: `\begin{tabular}{| L{4.2cm} | C{2.6cm} | S[table-format=9.6] |  C{2.6cm} | C{2.6cm} | C{2.6cm} |}`. I cannot see any problem in the last column.

Comment: Now I see the problem in the last column.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I don't see what's wrong: could you explain (or add an image)?

Comment: Thanks! How can numbers in all 4 columns be aligned? I can't seem to get it work. And yes, entries in the last column are not centered vertically...

Comment: A separate matter: In a column of type `S`, `{\centering} {\bfseries 1989}` is a bit redundant; `{\bfseries 1989}` suffices to center the **1989** entry.

Comment: @JosephWright someone else has added an image; in the last column the entries are shifted upwards.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ah: 'Not my fault', as the issue shows up even if you change the `S` column to something else :-) Probably one of those tricky things to deal with the last cell in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension to [Mico's wunderful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134041/16967). Instead of explicit struts the internal struts, which are automatically set by the `tabular` code, can be increased by redefining the scaling factor `\arraystretch`. The second example uses less lines with a smaller stretch factor:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{retain-explicit-plus}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \newcommand*{\thead}[1]{%
      \multicolumn{1}{X|}{\centering\textbf{#1}}%
    }%
    \sisetup{table-format=3.0}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|S|S|S|S[table-format=4.0]|}
      \hline
      & \thead{1988} & \thead{1989} & \thead{1990} & \thead{Change} \\
      \hline
      Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\
      \hline
      Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \newcommand*{\thead}[1]{%
      \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering\textbf{#1}}%
    }%
    \sisetup{table-format=3.0}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|SSSS[table-format=4.0]}
      & \thead{1988} & \thead{1989} & \thead{1990} & \thead{Change} \\
      \hline
      Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\
      Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The numbers are set with column specifier `S` of package `siunitx`, but the table is a `tabularx`, where the header row uses the `X` columns with `\centering`. This way the column is horizontally centered together with aligned numbers.
- The standard fonts have a quite large plus sign, thus I had to use `table-format=4.0` for this column to avoid overful `\hbox` warnings.
- There is also `\extrarowheight` of package `array` to add some space at the top of a row.

Answer (score 7):

I wonder if you might be better off redesigning the entire table. As it stands, there are a lot of extra commands to adjust vertical widths as well as the horizontal positions of the column entries. Here are some suggestions; implementation is shown further below.

- It looks like you want to force the table to take up the full width of the text block. To achieve this, consider using either a `tabular*` or a `tabularx` environment instead of forcing the table's contents into a `\makebox` instruction -- which, in any case, gives you something that's much wider than `\textwidth`.
- If you want to keep using vertical lines to separate the columns visually, consider inserting "struts" rather than using instructions such as `\\[1.8ex]`.
- Consider getting rid of the vertical rules entirely. Trust me, they won't be missed. Give it a try.
- Even better than using struts, consider loading the `booktabs` package and using its commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`. You'll automatically get proper spacing above and below these lines.
- If you don't want to use the `tabular*` environment, you could use the `tabularx` environment.
- To align the numerical entries of each column correctly, you could use the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=3.0,retain-explicit-plus=true}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\TB{\rule[-1.5ex]{0ex}{4.7ex}} % "top&bottom" strut
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Original form of table, minimally fixed. Note that the table is much too wide.}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\begin{tabular}{| L{4.2cm} | C{2.6cm} | S[table-format=9.6] |  C{2.6cm} | C{2.6cm} | C{2.6cm} |} 
\hline 
& \bfseries 1988& {\centering} {\bfseries 1989} & \bfseries 1990 & \bfseries Change \\ [2ex]
\hline
Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\ [1.8ex]
\hline
Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\ [1.8ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Correct width, use of \texttt{tabular*} environment and explicit struts, \texttt{c}~column types}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ |l|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c|c|c|c| } 
\hline 
\TB & \bfseries 1988& {\bfseries 1989} & \bfseries 1990 & \bfseries Change \\ 
\hline
Score\TB & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\ 
\hline
Percent High\TB & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{\texttt{tabular*} environment, \texttt{c}~column types, use \texttt{booktabs} package's rules (struts no longer needed!), get rid of vertical lines}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc } 
\toprule 
& \bfseries 1988& {\bfseries 1989} & \bfseries 1990 & \bfseries Change \\ 
\midrule
Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\ 
Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{\texttt{tabularx} environment, centered columns, \texttt{booktabs} package in use}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ lYYYY } 
\toprule 
& \bfseries 1988& {\bfseries 1989} & \bfseries 1990 & \bfseries Change \\ 
\midrule
Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\ 
Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{\texttt{tabular*} environment, columns of type \texttt{S}, \texttt{booktabs} package in use}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{S} } 
\toprule 
& \bfseries 1988& {\bfseries 1989} & {\bfseries 1990} & {\bfseries Change} \\ 
\midrule
Score & 249 & 234 & 266 & +17 \\ 
Percent High & 14 & 9 & 26 & +12 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```